# adding dynamic input box in a sql fetch array result with multiple rows

Tags: php, sql

I would like to make a page to edit some record which already saved at the sql , but sometime the record will have few rows of data with a same invoice number. I would like to show every detail from the invoice number, then with a input box to edit it

here is what i made so far (tsrnumber is the invoice number )
in this example i have 2 rows of data , test 1 and test2

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($localhost,$username,$password);

$tsrnumber = $_POST['tsrnumber'];

            $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tsr.tsrreport WHERE SN LIKE '%$tsrnumber%'");
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            echo    '<TR VALIGN=TOP>';
            echo    '<TD WIDTH=222 STYLE="border-top: 1px solid #00000a; border-bottom: 1px solid #00000a; border-left: 2.25pt solid #00000a; border-right: 1px solid #00000a; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0in; padding-left: 0.08in; padding-right: 0.08in">';
            echo    '<P LANG="en-GB" CLASS="western"><input type="text" name="PartsNo1" value="'.$row["7"].'" size="25"><BR>';
            echo    '</P>';
            echo    '</TD>';
            echo    '<TD WIDTH=368 STYLE="border-top: 1px solid #00000a; border-bottom: 1px solid #00000a; border-left: 1px solid #00000a; border-right: 1px solid #00000a; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0in; padding-left: 0.08in; padding-right: 0.08in">';
            echo    '<P LANG="en-GB" CLASS="western"><input type="text" name="Description1" value="'.$row["10"].'" size="35"><BR>';
            echo    '</P>';
            echo    '</TD>';
            echo    '<TD WIDTH=60 STYLE="border-top: 1px solid #00000a; border-bottom: 1px solid #00000a; border-left: 1px solid #00000a; border-right: 2.25pt solid #00000a; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0in; padding-left: 0.08in; padding-right: 0.08in">';;
            echo    '<P LANG="en-GB" CLASS="western"><input type="number" name="adjust" size="10" min="1" required><BR>';
            echo    '</P></TD></TR>';
            }

?>
```

in-order to make it look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHKUV.png)

but because i echo the input box and date like this , both row's input box name and ID will be the same , so i couldn't just post it to do $partno = $_POST['PartsNo1']; stuff at the back end.

i dont mind if you have a totally different approach, but easier for my situation here , i would love to hear it .

Much thanks

Comment: use a counter for running number like $i and increment it, concatenate it with your default name and id, which would result something like PartsNo1 PartsNo2 etc.

Comment: do you have an example to show me how to do it ? 
and also how do i set the back end page to match how many rows?
because not every time have 2 rows of data , it can be random
how to make those $partno = $_POST['PartsNo1']; and the query dynamic ?

Comment: something like this `$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$i++;
echo    '<P LANG="en-GB" CLASS="western"><input type="text" name="PartsNo'.$i.'" value="'.$row["7"].'" size="25"><BR>';
            `

Comment: thats work great !
But how the back end match the random number of rows to do $partno = $_POST['PartsNo1']; stuff ?

Comment: save that $i in a hidden variable when you post it with javascript, or if you're familian with creating JSON object, create the object containing the $i value, which contains how many field have been generated this way.